# Should we flag human-written questions that use code generated by ChatGPT?

Tags: discussion, rules, chatgpt

To be more specific, I flagged a question recently as it was of the type "ChatGPT generated this but I need some more help fixing this". But I was told by a mod that asking a question about [chatgpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt) code is fine, which led to my confusion here.

Here is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74958507/is-there-way-to-do-conditional-dictionary-definitions-in-python#comment132307898_74958507) I am referring to. And here is the response -

> asking a question about code produced by CGPT is fine. Not sure why you’d want to, but it is not banned. ChatGPT is not a programmer or a mathematician, it doesn’t use logic to construct code but is based on statistics. That rarely produces code that is actually fit for purpose.

I was under the impression that my flag should have been correct based on reading [what-should-i-do-if-i-suspect-that-a-question-or-answer-is-written-by-chatgpt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421988/what-should-i-do-if-i-suspect-that-a-question-or-answer-is-written-by-chatgpt,) and [are-questions-about-chatgpt-code-okay-to-ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422064/are-questions-about-chatgpt-code-okay-to-ask)

---

Don't the same reasons for which [chatgpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt) answers are [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned), apply to questions as well?

- It can be used to generate a ton of 'fake' questions on the platform
- It could attract upvotes, due to the well-formatted and "confident" looking content
- Bad questions created by [chatgpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt) will have to be handled the same way as any other question, but high volumes of such questions will waste precious moderator and community time.

Would love to hear from mods on the policy around this.

Comment: Yes. That's what banned means. No use of it to generate content is permitted

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine, there is a subtle difference here. The question wasnt generated by ChatGPT but the code the OP was referring to (for his doubts) was generated by ChatGPT. Does the same thing apply here?

Comment: Seems fine to me really, the origin of the code doesn’t really matter in most cases

Comment: The mod had a valid response to the original question as well - `the question isn't generated by the AI, only the code, about which the user has asked a question, in their own words. That's no different from asking a question about code found in documentation, or in a tutorial, or an answer on this site. It's attributed so we know the source.` This does make a ton of sense, but I am still confused about whether asking a question about ChatGPT code is part of the ban. because as @ZoestandswithUkraine mentioned, no use of generated content is permitted in questions or in answers.

Comment: I think my concern here is from the fact that HYPOTHETICALLY - I can create 20 different pieces of code from ChatGPT, run them, get an error and paste them as a question "in my own words" on SO for try to farm reputation. Isn't that a misuse of AI generated content on the platform?

Comment: Again, "banned", "no use of it to generate content is permitted". It's a blanket ban with no exceptions for the time being. Seems the mod in question doesn't roll with that though. [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422065/6296561) also sides with it not being okay, and has community support. The [initial announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/6296561) and [FAQ entry](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) does not make exceptions for partial CGPT content, because again, it's currently a blanket ban.

Comment: A mod deciding to overrule the current consensus makes this complicated precisely because of the confusion and discussions it creates

Comment: When the question asks about specifics about a piece of code, when it shouldn't matter if it came from a colleague, a school assignment, an OS lib, or chatGPT. It makes no sense to why it should be banned for those cases as well. If the whole question were written by chatGPT or the question itself is off-topic for other reasons, then it would be a different matter.

Comment: While I agree to that @Tom, doesn't that make the assessment of these cases super complicated? Where does one go from a heavily chatgpt generated question to a question asked in "their own words" but referring to a chatgpt question? If I have 20 lines of chatgpt code, 2 lines around the problem "in my own words" and 5 lines of trace (hypothetically) .. is that different from a 1 line chatgpt code and 100 lines of my explanation of the error i am facing? From what I understood myself, it was supposed to be a blanket ban as mentioned before.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think it matters here that the code came from ChatGPT. The reason being that one could cut out the ChatGPT code and it would still be the same question; the code is more of a naive attempt, not the actual focus of the question. That said, I also think that a "blanket ban" makes sense simply to avoid the work of assessing every single edge case, which is ultimately the reason for having the ban in the first place.

Comment: That's precisely why it's a blanket ban. Dealing with every single nuance is an exercise in unnecessary work. There's a _lot_ of variations, and every single one of them could cause a meta discussion and arguing if it wasn't a blanket ban. Banning every use of it to generate content is primarily meant to reduce work while we curb the tidal wave

Comment: @Zoe: the point is that this **isn't generating content for questions or answers**. If the user had asked the same question about the same code found a tutorial or blog post it'd have been fine, the difference is academical at this point. There is no need for us to vet this, there is no need to have to distinguish the AI content from real questions, etc. This is very neatly compatimentalised and clear, at least to me.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal: if you can write a coherent on-topic question then you deserve the rep, because **that's the goal of this site**. I doubt you will get much from it, though.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal: I'm not sure why you are hammering on at this. If the code is attributed, and it's not an AI generated question, it doesn't need flagging. There are tons and tons of questions with code and a traceback and very little prose, yet the code came from somewhere else. Dumb broken code is dumb broken code however someone found it.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal: the issue with AI generated posts is that they are easy to generate and so loads of users think that this is a ticket to quick rep. A good question about ChatGPT code is not easy to generate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, ok thanks for the clarification. Thanks a ton for taking the time out to elaborate!

Comment: Another example of such a question: [i found this trading strategy in chatgpt how do i manage to make it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74975876/1048572). It was quickly downvoted and closed.

Comment: ChatGPT does not write code, that's it.

Comment: ChatGPT does write code, definitely. Just not always very useful one. A bit like a beginner. There seems to be some way to go still.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine "..while we curb the tidal wave.." Any estimation how high the tidal wave is? What order of magnitude is the number of posts allegedly by ChatGPT every day?

Comment: @Trilarion last I heard, between 500 and 1500

Comment: @Zoe stands with Ukraine,  we shouldn't bàn code pasted into a question from chat GPT because maybe the OP tried the solution provided by chat GPT and the code didn't compile or didn't work, so OP is just seeking help from an experienced engineer on why the code doesn't work or why it doesn't compile. Don't ban code from chat GPT because code is code, even if it's generated by AI.

Comment: code is code even if it's generated by AI. SO banning chat GPT is just like America feeling insecure about Japanese technological supremacy in the 80s but the Japs are still better.

Comment: @FlaviusStandswithRussia Text is text even if it was generated by ChatGPT. Still there are viable reasons to ban text generated by ChatGPT. A blanket acceptance of code generated by ChatGPT would likely run into the same problems.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, but OP could paste the same code from other sites. Why is chat GPT excluded? I mean have pasted code from official doc site of python here many a times. why is chat GPT an exception?

Comment: @FlaviusStandswithRussia There is *one* official Python docs that you can copy paste *one* attempt/example each. ChatGPT can provide a practically infinite amount of attempts/examples. Treating these as equivalent isn't realistic.

Comment: @FlaviusStandswithRussia You're beating a dead horse here. It's been over two weeks and the consensus is I'm wrong

Comment: I see that these question often fall in [this category](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328017/861716).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The point here is that the specific ***question* was not written by ChatGPT**.

There is a difference between having ChatGPT write the question for you, and asking a question (in your own words) about something that ChatGPT generated. The former is prohibited; the latter is fine, provided the question is otherwise on-topic, and you attribute the source of the code.

Asking a question *about* ChatGPT output is no different from asking questions about other code you found somewhere, be that documentation, a tutorial, or another Stack Overflow answer.

Note that there may be grounds to close such a question as off-topic, but not because ChatGPT was involved, but simply because of the way the question is worded. It could be too broad (asking us to explain the whole thing), a typo (ChatGPT didn't put in the required punctuation), etc. That's not a reason to flag for moderator attention; that's a reason to flag or vote to close.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @martijnpieters, could you also elaborate on how the latter `(asking a question (in your own words) about something that ChatGPT generated)` fits in with the blanket ban as well?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal: the ban is clear: don't generate questions or answers or comments with AI. This isn't such a case.

Comment: So hypothetically (mentioned this as a comment before), if  someone generated 20 pieces of code, ran them, copied the error messages and wrapped the code + trace in a problem description and posted 20 questions, that is acceptable and not banned? just to clarify

Comment: @AkshaySehgal: If the question is about why the code produces error messages, yes, that's fine. I think that trusting ChatGPT to the point that you are surprised to see errors is unwise, but I'm not here to judge why others seem to expect ChatGPT to know about logic, maths and other programming skills.

Comment: Completely understand @martijnpieters and agree with that, but then based on your answer is it fine for me to understand that `"Help me fix this ChatGPT generated Code"` type questions are valid? And that the answer to this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422064/are-questions-about-chatgpt-code-okay-to-ask) is invalid?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal FWIW, the question in question *does* ask "How do I do this?", as advised in the post you link to. It just uses ChatGPT code as a cheap way to generate an attempt, not as the sole point of the question.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal: the hypothetical situation that MisterMiyagi there alludes to is not specific to ChatGPT.

Comment: Stack Overflow licensing policy is that ***user contributions [are] licensed under CC BY-SA***, but if someone posts ChatGPT generated code, can they actually agree to such a license?

Comment: @dbc that’s an interesting issue, to which I have no answer. If there _is_ a license violation then presumably there’ll be an injured party that can file a DMCA takedown.

Comment: I appreciate the logic here, but I think there are more subtleties in allowing questions about chatGPT-generated code that are worth considering. I fear we will become the clean-up service for reams of chatGPT generated code that is close but still contains at least some complete nonsense. I remember one piece of python code that looked 100% correct except for a single import statement at the beginning that was utter garbage but still looked convincing. Do we want to answer those questions? We don't have reams of these yet so perhaps my concerns are premature.

Comment: It is not OK to spam 20 questions at once (and probably runs into a ban anyway). It is not ok to copy code from anywhere as a cheap substitution for one's own attempt. It is not OK to post a chunk of code without having a clue and asking us to debug/fix it. All of these are reasons to downvote for lack of effort, and vote to close. But it doesn't matter whether the asker uses ChatGPT for this - it also happens without, and stating the source of the copied code is still better than not stating it at all. For now, current moderation tools suffice to cope with this, we don't need a complete ban.

Comment: Still expect such questions to be downvoted though. I wouldn't use the word "fine" myself but more the "it's... fine I guess?" variant. You can try, but don't go writing angry meta posts about it when you get automatically banned from asking questions because of it.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk there haven’t been many questions and even fewer that were on topic. The post that sparked this debate was closed as a duplicate, and the error made was not unlike something many newbies might have made. Had the term “ChatGPT” not been included in the post no-one would have noticed.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Plus, the post quality system will land you in post ban hell a lot quicker for bad questions than it does for bad answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the ban is **not** clear, especially since the Note in the ban states _"the ban applies to all content on Stack Overflow, except each user's profile content"_  So that would seem to apply to asking questions about ChatGPT generated code.  The text of the note in the ban is overreaching and needs to be qualified to clarify this particular situation to explicitly say that it does not apply to human-generated questions about ChatGPT-generated code.

Comment: In the questions I've seen there is generally a disconnect between the goal the OP was hoping to achieve and the question about why the code written by ChatGPT wasn't working. This too me falls well withing the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: "Asking a question about CGPT is no different from asking about other code you found somewhere..."  I guess, but then I also downvote and close questions that are  "I pasted in some code I found on the web and it doesn't work" types of questions too.  And all the questions I've seen about CGPT code have fallen into this very lazy and not useful to anyone else category.

Comment: "Asking a question about ChatGPT output is no different from asking questions about other code you found somewhere, be that documentation, a tutorial, or another Stack Overflow answer." Or in other words, using chatgpt to *help* generate your post is ok (at least that's how I understood your sentence), as long as it's not incoherent or blatantly off-topic. Some people just don't seem to get this basic concept

Comment: Is illustrating your answer with code generated by ChatGPT any different from doing the same with code found somewhere on the internet? If it is, then why are questions treated differently from answers? If it is not, then what exactly is banned?

Comment: This position is in violation of the [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1), which states "***All* use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.**" which means you cannot ask a question about ChatGPT/genAI code, either. Please adjust the response here or adjust the policy to reflect what is actually being enforced.

Comment: @MartijnPieters as others have pointed out, you’re simply mistaken. The ban indicates this answer is wrong, it’s straightforward.

Answer (score 46):

**It seems highly unlikely to me** that ChatGPT code could support a worthwhile question. A question using such code would presumably be either:

- "Does this ChatGPT generated code do what it's intended to do?" **We aren't a debugging service**, and we certainly aren't a *testing* service.
- "What does this ChatGPT generated code do?" - [almost certainly **needs more focus**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894); and if properly focused, there would be no reason to leave behind enough code for it to still have any signature of AI generation.
- "I tried using this ChatGPT generated code in my project, and it doesn't do what I want it to do; how do I fix it?" - almost certainly **needs debugging details**, *even if* the user has included example input, a stack trace, a description of expected output etc. The problem is that the code will not be a *minimal* reproducible example. Since we aren't a debugging service, the question needs to be about the specific part of the code *that causes the problem*; this entails that OP is responsible for *determining* which part that is.
- "I have a problem with my code; to maintain NDA, I used ChatGPT to generate a MRE...." - **really**? And you verified by hand that the generated MRE is minimal, reproducible, and exemplifies the actual problem? Was that easier than actually just writing the code by hand, or copying and pasting the relevant lines and changing some variable names? Do you also use ChatGPT to create unit tests, and trust the result of those tests without human intervention?

---

That said, we care about the **questions**, not the code. The **reason** we care about banning ChatGPT content is because the ease of generating it means that relatively few users could easily overwhelm the capacity of moderators and curators (who are already overwhelmed by thousands of almost-all-worthless new questions per day). Having to write everything by hand except the actual code, certainly mitigates the problem.

Comment: The answer to "why doesn't this ChatGPT code do what I want?" is always the same: ChatGPT is a language model. It has no understanding of programming, computer science, or your goals. The code doesn't do what you want because ChatGPT is not an appropriate tool for generating code you couldn't have written yourself.

Comment: @JamesWestman it has as much understanding of programming as it does English, which is a surprisingly good ability to generate a plausible stream of convincing BS - and the most convincing BS is BS that happens to be correct - but not always.

Comment: @user253751 Right. If you ask a magic 8 ball a question and then come to Stack Overflow asking if that answer is correct, well, you should just ask us your original question. If it's on topic.

Comment: As true as all of this may be, it fundamentally does not answer the question that was asked here, which is whether questions that contain code generated by ChatGPT should be flagged *as using code generated by ChatGPT*, under our current, blanket ban of all ChatGPT-generated content.

Comment: I'm not convinced by the third and fourth point. The M in MRE very often does not get taken verbatim; it's very common to have bloated examples. Using ChatGPT to generate debugging questions would very well be doable with the current curation standards. It's convincing that moderators don't see this happening so it doesn't need special handling, but it's not convincing to me that that regular curation could handle such questions *if* people were to press our on-topic debugging capabilities.

Comment: My point is that "current curation standards" are a) abysmal and b) due to their history of being applied the same way, the reason why I constantly am unable to find canonical duplicates that should be obvious.

Comment: "it's not convincing to me that that regular curation could handle such questions if people were to press our on-topic debugging capabilities" - "our on-topic debugging capabilities" are approximately zero, and we know this; which **is exactly why** we should demand that questions not actually test those capabilities. As I've explained before: putting the appropriate work into a debugging question *makes it effectively not a debugging question any more*.

Answer (score -3):

Two points I feel like I have to bring up here:

- We are not a code-generating service
- We are not a debugging service

There are exceptions to this, however.

ChatGPT, especially [GPT-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPT-4), has evolved somewhat... over the course of the years it has been with us. With this said, its capabilities in coding is mostly limited to the two points mentioned above. Therefore, if you ask it to generate code a tad bit advanced, or debug a program, it **will not** yield sufficient results to be considered for SO. However, personally I feel like the code-generating feature is useful at times. As many say, ask a question in the form that you would, to your colleague who has to catch a bus in 5 minutes. Make it concise and easily readable. Therefore, the answer-posters should not have to spend a lot of time answering a question.

I believe that ChatGPT is useful in the aspect of generating examples. It does a good job in generating easily understandable code snippets, since it uses descriptive variable/function names, explained what parts of the code do in comments, and usually add an explanation of the code below or before. Of course, the code is still error-prone, so if used for Stack Overflow would need to be checked over and run to make sure they work.

Comment: This is not the place to argue in favor of ChatGPT. The policy is set already. LLM-generated text is not allowed on SO.