# What to do with edits to questions "To verify @<username>'s answer that this is not possible. I had the following Q&A with Chat GPT"

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, chatgpt

I have answered a question as "It's not possible" having a two of tags that I'm gold tag badge holder and provided the link to the official doc about the related feature.

The OP replied to the answer "I could not find absolute confirmation that *X feature* are not possible from *Y context*", that it's a fair reply / request for clarification but also edited the question saying

> To verify @<username>'s answer that this is not possible. I had the following Q&A with Chat GPT [sic]

then pasted the conversation held with ChatGPT which claims that the answer is wrong and that the feature is actually available.

So I edited my answer to provide more details but now I have doubts if those edits to add ChatGPT conversations to a question should be allowed. I think that instead, the OP should wait for the community to vote on the answer and/or offer a bounty to draw attention or something alike according to the "traditional" SO workings as copying/pasting a conversation with ChatGPT is like transcribing a conversation held with a third party that is known as a non-reliable source.

Should the conversation with ChatGPT be removed as chitchat? (ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

---

Derived from the early comments to this question

Should the wording "To verify..." be changed to make it more accordingly to be as part of a OP's an additional research effort considering that at the time that the edit occurred the answer hadn't any vote?

Related

- [Is "this is not possible" an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261168/1595451)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: The ChatGPT conversion is not a confirmation of the answer, but claims that the answer is wrong. Leaving aside the ChatGPT problem, I'd consider it additional research than an answer attempt.

Comment: Using ChatGPT to "prove" an answer is "wrong" feels more than a little ironic, considering how wrong the string of characters it vomits out can be at times...

Comment: This sounds like the question has had meta commentary added to it, which should be rolled back. The question should be complete on its own. If the user who wrote the question wants to let a user know that the answer wasn't what they wanted/needed then comments can be used. If they are looking for a different answer they should edit the question to explain what they need, not why an existing answer is right/wrong.

Comment: I think you're also going way too deep into how ChatGPT works in your answer. Just state that it's unreliable, and link to the ban announcement. Don't give "them" incentive to debate it.

Comment: GPT can be asked to express certain opinions, or craft rebuttals to arguments. People who cite GPT output to call someone else Wrong on the Internet (TM) are either self-deluding, way too naive, or trolling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've removed all of the extraneous content about searching and ChatGPT from the question, along with the text you included in your answer responding to it.

1. Answers don't belong in questions, so the additional content edited into the question would have been inappropriate, even if it wasn't from ChatGPT. Such edits should be rolled back. I typically leave a comment similar to:

   > I've rolled back your edit adding an answer in your question. I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should ****not**** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to **clarify the question**, but not to include an answer within the question. You could create your own answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own answer). When you've solved the problem yourself, [[posting an answer to your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer)](/help/self-answer).
2. Content generated by ChatGPT is banned. See "[Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/3773011)". Also note "[Should we flag human-written questions that use code generated by ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422439/3773011)" for some subtleties.
3. Some of the content which I removed was in the initial revision of the question. It was about searching and asking ChatGPT, along with asking the additional debugging question for the ChatGPT generated code. That material was really extraneous to the "how to" question which was the real question being asked there. Thus, it was really distracting from the real question. Asking about debugging the ChatGPT generated code was actually a second, separate question, which, in this case, really made the overall question posted too broad/needs focus, so the question could have been closed as that. But, overall, the real question that the author was asking was the "how to" question. So, *in this case*, the extraneous debugging question could be edited out, leaving the main question.

   [Note: I'm not saying that the debugging portions of all "how to" questions should always be edited out. I'm merely saying that, IMO, *in this case* that was a reasonable thing to do, particularly given that the code was generated by ChatGPT and, thus, didn't even have the intent of being correct.]

Comment: "Content generated by ChatGPT is banned. See "Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned". Also note "Should we flag human-written questions that use code generated by ChatGPT?" for some subtleties." This part reads awkwardly.